# sed + replace only the second match word

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, perl

we have the following file:

```
more /tmp/file

Allow,Deny
Allow,Deny
```

we want to change only the second match word ( to replace Allow,Deny with Deny,Allow )

so we did

```
sed 's/Allow,Deny/Deny,Allow/1'  /tmp/file

Deny,Allow
Deny,Allow
```

but it replace both them

while the expected results:

```
Allow,Deny
Deny,Allow
```

how to replace only the second ,match word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to change only the second match word ( to replace Allow,Deny with
>   Deny,Allow )

**sed** solution:

Sample `tmp_file`:

```
Allow,Deny
Allow,Deny
Allow,Deny
Allow,Deny
```

---

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/Allow,Deny/Deny,Allow/2' tmp_file
```

The output:

```
Allow,Deny
Deny,Allow
Allow,Deny
Allow,Deny
```

Answer (score 3):

Another sed solution.

```
sed '0,/Allow/!{0,/Allow/s/Allow/Deny/}' /tmp/file
```

Here we match the first `Allow` then we ignore the substitution for the first `Allow` we come across and substitute the next line.

To give an idea, the following would substitute the second and fourth since we used `N;`

```
sed '0,/Allow/!{N;/Allow/s/Allow/Deny/}'
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk '/Allow/{c++; if (c==2) { sub("Allow","Deny")}}1'
```

We match `Allow` then keep a counter `c`. If this matches the `2` second occurrence then we substitute it.